# How to read Json in Google Data Studio, Big Query, Json

Tags: json, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am using Big Query for as a cloud data warehouse and DataStudio for vizualisation.

In Big Query I have a table with a column named `data` written in JSON.  I only want to extract what is inside the field "city".

This formula below that someone gave me worked to extract what is inside the field "title". I used it to create a field in DataStudio.

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '"title":(.+)","ur'), "\"", "")
```

So, I tried in multiple ways to reuse this formula for the "city" field, but it hasn't worked. I don't understand this code.

What's inside my column data:

```
 {
    "address":{
        "city":"This is what i want",
        "country":"blablabla",
        "lineAdresse":"blablabla",
        "region":"blablabla",
        "zipCode":"blablabla"
    },
    "contract":"blablabla",
    "dataType":"blablabla",
    "description":"blablabla",
    "endDate":{
        "_seconds":1625841747,
        "_nanoseconds":690000000
    },
    "entreprise":{
        "denomination":"blabla",
        "description":"1",
        "logo":"blablabla",
        "blabla":"blablabla",
        "verified":"false"
    },
    "id":"16256R8TOUHJG",
    "idEntreprise":"blablabla",
    "jobType":"blablabla",
    "listInfosRh":null,
    "listeCandidats":[
        
    ],
    "field":0,
    "field":0,
    "field":14,
    "field":"1625834547690",
    "field":true,
    "field":"",
    "field":"ref1625834547690",
    "skills":[
        "field",
        "field",
        "field"
    ],
    "startDate":{
        "_seconds":1625841747,
        "_nanoseconds":690000000
    },
    "status":true,
    "title":"this I can extract",
    "urlRedirection":"blablabla",
    "validated":true
}
```

If anyone knows the formula to put in Data Studio to extract what's inside `city` and can explain it to me, this would help a lot.

Here's the formula I tried but where I got "null" result:

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data,'"city":/{([^}]*)}/'),"\"","") >>null
```

I tried this one but it wouldn't stop at the city. I got the address, the region, zipcode and all the rest after:

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '"city":(.+)","ur'), "\"", "")
```

Comment: It would help your question if you could share in the question the formulas that you have tried and what the results were of those failed attempts.

Comment: Thank you, for instance when I try REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '"title":(.+)","ur'), "\"", "") I get the title "this I can extract" but when I try 
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '"city":(.+) ","ur'), "\"", "")
nothing happens, I can't figure out what regex formula to use to extract the city for instance, I've tried also this but it is not working 
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '"city ":\s* "[^ "]+?([^\/" ]+) "", "")
REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(data,'"city":/{([^}]*)}/'),"\"","") >>null
and from this source (still not working) REGEXP_EXTRACT(data,'"city":"((\\"|[^"!,])*)"')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to parse a JSON in a text field by ignoring any hierarchy and only looking for a specific field. In your case the field names were `title` and `city` . Please be aware that this approach is not save for user entered data: By setting the value of the `"city":"\" hide \""` the script cannot extract the city.

```
select *,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'"title":\s*"([^"]+)') as title,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'"city":\s*"([^"]+)') as city

from(
Select ' {     "address":{         "city":"This is what i want",         "country":"blablabla",         "lineAdresse":"blablabla",         "region":"blablabla",         "zipCode":"blablabla"     },     "contract":"blablabla",     "dataType":"blablabla",     "description":"blablabla",     "endDate":{         "_seconds":1625841747,         "_nanoseconds":690000000     },     "entreprise":{         "denomination":"blabla",         "description":"1",         "logo":"blablabla",         "blabla":"blablabla",         "verified":"false"     },     "id":"16256R8TOUHJG",     "idEntreprise":"blablabla",     "jobType":"blablabla",     "listInfosRh":null,     "listeCandidats":[              ],     "field":0,     "field":0,     "field":14,     "field":"1625834547690",     "field":true,     "field":"",     "field":"ref1625834547690",     "skills":[         "field",         "field",         "field"     ],     "startDate":{         "_seconds":1625841747,         "_nanoseconds":690000000     },     "status":true,     "title":"this I can extract",     "urlRedirection":"blablabla",     "validated":true }' as data
)
```